# Activities: Assigning Tasks to a Queue(Spring 20) Visible to non Members of the Queue in Activity Composer Lighting component

Tags: lightning-experience, activities, spring-20

I am trying the new feature of spring 20 "**Assign the Tasks to the Queue**".
[Assign to Queue](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_activities_task_queues.htm)  The issue I am facing here is the Activities are shown to none members of the Queue in the Activity Composer standard Lightning component.

[image]

My scenario is that the activities created by the one group of people should not be visible to another group Activities

I am i missing something in here ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Check the sharing rules and custom sharing rules. Check the OWD setting as well.

Comment: The Activities OWD is private and no sharing rules on the activities.